# Extracting atmosphere opacity using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, landsat

I met some doubts when I try to extract Landsat surface reflection product's atmosphere opacity.

the code  is :

```js
var inCollection7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR").filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016,2018,'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,8,'month')).filterBounds(geometry);

var list=inCollection7.toList(10)

var test_img7= ee.Image(list.get(0))

print('test_img7',test_img7)

Map.addLayer(test_img7.select('sr_atmos_opacity'),{},'Landsat7_Opacity')
```

the question is :

1. why the Landsat7's atmosphere opacity' value is not from 0 to 0.3 or more（like the data description）？

[image: data description]

[![error][2]][2]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code and properly format it rather than providing a link or screenshot to the code. That way if the url goes 404 the code is still preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `sr_atmos_opacity` it says 0.001, that is the scale. So, you have to multiply the value by the scale to get the actual value.

```js
var inCollection7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
                       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016,2018,'year'))
                       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,3,'month'))
                       .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'greater_than', 80)
                       .filterBounds(geometry);

var list=inCollection7.toList(10)

var test_img7= ee.Image(list.get(0))

print('test_img7',test_img7)

var getClass = function(image, lowerLimit, upperLimit, newValue) {
  var mask = image.gte(lowerLimit).and(image.lt(upperLimit))
  return mask.multiply(newValue)
}

var atm = test_img7.select('sr_atmos_opacity').multiply(0.001)

var clear = getClass(atm, -32, 0.1, 0)
var average = getClass(atm, 0.1, 0.3, 1)
var hazy = getClass(atm, 0.31, 32, 2)

var clas = clear.add(average).add(hazy).rename('class')

Map.addLayer(clas,{min:0, max:2, palette:['blue', 'green', 'gray']}, 'atmos opacity')
Map.addLayer(test_img7 ,{bands:['B4', 'B5', 'B3'], min:0, max:5000}, 'img', false)
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d508bb32c4b61001a3f412f862a5fed2